spi通信でMOSI信号とsck(クロック）信号の波形が出力されない
現在、spresenseのメインボードでspi通信を行うためにプログラムを書いており、
実現したいことは、0x02というデータを送信するプログラムを実行しmosi信号、CS信号、sck(クロック）信号波形をオシロスコープで確認することです。
しかし現状として、何故かメインボードからCS信号だけが確認でき、mosi信号とsck信号が全く波形として出ません。
これまでに確認したこととしては
メインボードの故障の可能性があると考え、新しい機体を購入したが、全く同じ結果となった。
同じプログラムを実行し、拡張ボードのピンからはmosi信号、CS信号、sck信号が確認できた。
という状況です。
現在動かしているプログラムは以下のようになります。
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SPI.h>  

#define CS 20

SPISettings mySPISettings = SPISettings(500000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0); 

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  SPI.begin();
}

void loop() {
  SPI.beginTransaction(mySPISettings); 

  digitalWrite(CS, LOW); 

  SPI.transfer(0x02);

  digitalWrite(CS, HIGH);  

  SPI.endTransaction();
}



SPI信号の挙動についてここに詳しく載っていました。
https://developer.sony.com/spresense/development-guides/arduino_developer_guide_ja.html#_機能と制限
SPI CS信号はハードウェアで自動で制御されるので、digitalWrite() で制御する必要は無い、逆に制御してしまうとピンモードがSPIからGPIOへ切り替わってしまうので、CS信号しか観測できないという質問にある症状になってしまうと思います。
次のように digitalWrite() を削除して信号を観測してみてください。
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SPI.h>  

SPISettings mySPISettings = SPISettings(500000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0); 

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  SPI.begin();
}

void loop() {
  SPI.beginTransaction(mySPISettings); 

  SPI.transfer(0x02);

  SPI.endTransaction();
}

